# Conflict between pandas and erlport?

Tags: python, erlang, pandas

I am passing data between erlang and python using erlport, following the example here:
http://erlport.org/docs/python.html

the python file I'm calling only contains the line:

```
import pandas as pd
```

I am getting the error:

```
** exception error: {python,'exceptions.AttributeError',
                            "'function' object has no attribute 'lower'",
                            [{<<"/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/format.py">>,
                              1701,<<"detect_console_encoding">>,
                              <<"if not encoding or 'ascii' in encoding.lower():  # try again for something bette"...>>},
                             {<<"/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/config_init.py">>,
                              234,<<"<module>">>,
                              <<"cf.register_option('encoding', detect_console_encoding(), pc_encoding_doc,">>},
                             {<<"/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py">>,
                              25,<<"<module>">>,<<"import pandas.core.config_init">>},
                             {<<"/Documents/data-algorithms/Alg"...>>,
                              3,<<"<module>">>,<<"import pandas as pd">>},
                             {<<"/Documents/testki"...>>,
                              237,<<"_incoming_call">>,
                              <<"f = __import__(module, {}, {}, [objects[0]])">>},
                             {<<"/Documents/te"...>>,
                              245,<<"_call_with_error_handler">>,<<"function(*args)">>}]}
     in function  erlport:call/3 (src/erlport.erl, line 234)
     in call from algo_tester:start/0 (src/algo_tester.erl, line 27)
```

I can get rid of the error by commenting out the following two lines in `/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/config_init.py`:

```
234        cf.register_option('encoding', detect_console_encoding(), pc_encoding_doc,
235                            validator=is_text)
```

but then print doesn't work any longer.

Has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was answered on GitHub:

- ErlPort's issue: https://github.com/hdima/erlport/issues/11
- Pandas' issue: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5687